# How to loop a BeautifulSoup data from many links into a single csv

Tags: python, pandas, loops, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape some data and insert it into CSV files and am doing this using a while loop.

However, is there a way to put all the data into a single CSV file instead of 20 different CSV files.

```
def make_soup(url):
    thepage =urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'lxml')
    return soupdata





day = 1

while (day<20):
    soup = make_soup("http://link"+str(day))
    data_list= [record.text for record in soup.find_all("td")]
    py=pd.DataFrame(data_list)
    date=py.iloc[24:-11]
    plist = pd.concat([date.iloc[s:s+3].reset_index(drop=True).T for s in 
  range(0,len(date), 3)]).reset_index(drop=True)
    plist.columns = ['Salary','Name',"Time"]
    day = day + 1
    results=plist.to_csv("result"+str(day)+".csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.concat` to join 20 plists together then export at the end:

```
day = 1
plists = []

while day < 20:
    ...
    day += 1
    plists.append(plist)

pd.concat(plists, ignore_index=True).to_csv('all_plist.csv')
```